# filter data using addFieldToFilter() Condition in block file magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I need to filter values based on and condition in my custom table

---

id    status   categoryid

---

and i have to filter data according to status and categoryid
my current code is

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
```

how can i filter data based on status and categoryid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento 2.2:**

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collecionFactory;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

**Then anywhere else in your class you can do:**

```
$collection = $this->collecionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->setPageSize(1);

if ($collection->getSize()) {
    $categoryId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
}
```